# Static class for constants with reference to java resources

Tags: java, android, singleton, constants

I want to store the colors I use in the **colors.xml** file. In addition to using them in an `xml-layout`, I also want to use these colors in my Java code, when drawing things to the Canvas.

The thing is, I am not always using the colors in a class that extends Application. For example, I have classes for objects that get drawn to the Canvas.

The thing is, I don't want to store the context in each class that needs access to my resources file.

My current solution is the following:

**colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorOne">#123456</color>
</resources>
```

A static class called Attributes for constants, including colors:

```
public class Attributes {
    private static final Resources RESOURCES = MainActivity.getContext().getResources();

    public static final int ONE_COLOR = RESOURCES.getColor(R.color.colorOne);
    public static final int SOME_OTHER_CONSTANT = 1;
}
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static Context context;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.context = getApplicationContext();

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    public static Context getContext() {
        return context;
    }
}
```

And, finally in my object class:

```
public class ScreenArea {
    private Rect area;
    private Paint paint;

    public ScreenArea(Rect area) {
        this.area = area;
        paint = new Paint();
        paint.setColor(Attributes.COLOR_ONE);
    }

    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawRect(area, paint);
    }
}
```

Okay, so first of all, this works. But, I am wondering if this is the right way to go. I have been reading about the Singleton class, but most examples are very basic an not focusing on storing constants, like I am doing right now.

So my questions:

- Is this the right way to go or should I implement a Singleton?
- If so, who can point me in the right direction?

Comment: _"Is this the right way to go or should I implement a Singleton?"_ Using a _Singleton_ is rarely a good decision.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: So, what is your suggestion?

Comment: Not to use a Singleton.

Comment: And leave it the way I am currently doing? Doesn't that impose risks, considering app lifecycles etc?

Answer (score 2):

well as pointed out using singletons is considered bad practice and using global constants in an object-orientatd world is bad practice as well...

So, what is your suggestion?

---

### Consider the purpose of the attribute

you want to define a app-specific attribute (color), an attribute you want to configure - this is the very reason why you use ressources, right. Or do you want to define a constant?

### 1. it's a constant

if you don't want to specify a configurable attribute you should define a **constant** in your app

```
private static final int COLOR_ONE = 0x123456;
```

### 2. it's an attribute

but if you want to specify a configurable attribute you simply define it as such in your app:

```
int colorOne = MainActivity.getContext().getResources().getColor(R.color.colorOne);
```

you are right, this might be a bit *intricately* so it would be just as simple to wrap this call in a method

```
private int getColorFromRessource(int colorId){
    return MainActivity.getContext().getResources().getColor(colorId); 
}
```

this would be applied in your setup of the `Paint` in an quite easy way:

```
public ScreenArea(Rect area) {
    this.area = area;
    paint = new Paint();
    paint.setColor(getColorFromRessource(R.color.colorOne)); //obvious
  //paint.setColor(Attributes.COLOR_ONE);  far less obvious
}
```

Comment: I think this is pretty much what I am trying to do. The main difference is that I have defined a constant to store the color, where you wrap it all in a method. The advantage of the method is that you don't have a singleton. The disadvantage, I guess is that using a constant is more efficient, right?

Comment: Well it's up to you - if your color **is a constant** then you should define a constant in your code... if your color **is an attribute** you should define it in your xml and access it via the methods - just as answered above...